# after instalation SML/NJ - No command 'sml' found on ubuntu 12.04 at terminal

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line

I installed SML/NJ according this instruction [Downloads Unix](http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.75/):

`The only file you need to download manually is config.tgz. Unpack, configure by editing   config/targets, and install by running config/install.sh. The installer automatically   downloads any additional files it might need. For more information, see INSTALL.`

I didn't configure `config/targets` and let it by default.
I installed all this in `/usr/local/SML/configure`

After this I run from SML folder - `config/install.sh`

It build all necessary dependance as ml-lpt.tgz, cml.tgz ... into SML folder (I checked).

But after prompt `config/install.sh: Installation complete.`

I checked typed `sml` at terminal:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:/usr/local/SML$ sml
No command 'sml' found, did you mean:
 Command 'wml' from package 'wml' (universe)
 Command 'smi' from package 'scmxx' (universe)
 Command 'smc' from package 'smc' (universe)
 Command 'sma' from package 'sma' (universe)
 Command 'sol' from package 'aisleriot' (main)
 Command 'sm' from package 'sm' (universe)
 Command 'sl' from package 'sl' (universe)
sml: command not found
```

It should be smt like this - `Standard ML of New Jersey v110.75 [built: ...]`

**Edit:**

after running `ls -l /usr/local/SML/`:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ ls -l /usr/local/SML/
total 8668
drwxrwxr-x  3 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep  2 23:35 base
drwxrwxr-x  4 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep  2 23:47 bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art 5848139 Sep 29  2012 boot.x86-unix.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  5 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep 29  2012 ckit
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art  194523 Sep 29  2012 ckit.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  5 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep 29  2012 cml
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art  105902 Sep 29  2012 cml.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  4 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep  3 00:00 config
drwxrwxr-x 36 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep  2 23:37 lib
drwxr-xr-x  5 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep  2 23:47 ml-burg
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art   36339 Sep 29  2012 ml-burg.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  4 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep  2 23:47 ml-lex
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art   33154 Sep 29  2012 ml-lex.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  8 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep 29  2012 ml-lpt
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art  256313 Sep 29  2012 ml-lpt.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 40 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep 29  2012 MLRISC
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art 1422655 Sep 29  2012 MLRISC.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  7 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep 29  2012 ml-yacc
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art   99940 Sep 29  2012 ml-yacc.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  4 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep 29  2012 nlffi
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art   74481 Sep 29  2012 nlffi.tgz
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art  324054 Sep 29  2012 runtime.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 17 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep 29  2012 smlnj-lib
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art  396628 Sep 29  2012 smlnj-lib.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  3 nazar_art nazar_art    4096 Sep  2 23:37 trace-debug-profile
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazar_art nazar_art    3902 Sep 29  2012 trace-debug-profile.tgz
```

***- Why this happen?

 - How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sml` is in `/usr/local/SML` directory, you should use it's relative path:

```
cd /usr/local/SML/bin
./sml
```

or absolute path:

```
/usr/local/SML/bin/sml
```

Or [add `/usr/local/SML/bin` directory to your PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path).

More about: [About the Use of Dot-Slash in Commands](http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html).

Comment: I did this about `./sml` it shows `bash: ./sml: No such file or directory`. But about adding this to my path. At this tutorial they didn't write nothing necessary about this, and this is their main site `http://www.smlnj.org`. What do you thisnk about this?

Comment: @What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/SML/` command? As you can see there is no `sml` file there.

Comment: I updated question. But `sml` at console should open the SML console - `Standard ML of New Jersey v110.75 [built: ...]` and open SML console, you can type `1 + 1;` + Enter.  the SML interpreter should print something like this: `val it = 2 : int`.  To exit the interpreter, `type Control-D`.

Comment: @nazar_art Have you read http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.75/NOTES/INSTALL ? There is a section: *2.5.  What needs to be on my PATH?* Also, I edited my answer.